# Gitlab-runner unable to access gitlab web port 80 but Gitlab-runner register succeed

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ce

Gitlab and Runner is running on k8s.

1. I can `git clone`, `git push`.
2. Gitlab version ce 16.5.0
3. Git-runner version  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner:alpine-v16.6.0
4. UFW is disable.
5. deploy both by helm

When I try gitlab-ci, I got this error.
Full error

```bash
Running with gitlab-runner 16.6.0 (3046fee8)
  on gitlab-runner-76687b884d-ljmgh zzAt8-S8, system ID: r_ecd1uLtBtA3a
Preparing the "kubernetes" executor
00:00
Using Kubernetes namespace: gitlab
Using Kubernetes executor with image alpine ...
Using attach strategy to execute scripts...
Preparing environment
00:10
Using FF_USE_POD_ACTIVE_DEADLINE_SECONDS, the Pod activeDeadlineSeconds will be set to the job timeout: 1h0m0s...
Waiting for pod gitlab/runner-zzat8-s8-project-1-concurrent-0-s345dpl6 to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab/runner-zzat8-s8-project-1-concurrent-0-s345dpl6 to be running, status is Pending
    ContainersNotInitialized: "containers with incomplete status: [init-permissions]"
    ContainersNotReady: "containers with unready status: [build helper]"
    ContainersNotReady: "containers with unready status: [build helper]"
Waiting for pod gitlab/runner-zzat8-s8-project-1-concurrent-0-s345dpl6 to be running, status is Pending
    ContainersNotReady: "containers with unready status: [build helper]"
    ContainersNotReady: "containers with unready status: [build helper]"
Running on runner-zzat8-s8-project-1-concurrent-0-s345dpl6 via gitlab-runner-76687b884d-ljmgh...
Getting source from Git repository
00:02
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/devops/kafka/.git/
Created fresh repository.
fatal: unable to access 'http://gitlab.khaolakonline.com/devops/kafka.git/': Failed to connect to gitlab.khaolakonline.com port 80 after 1061 ms: Couldn't connect to server
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

Checking Network

```bash
root@ansible-server:~# kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- nslookup gitlab-webservice-default.gitlab
Server:         169.254.25.10
Address:        169.254.25.10#53

Name:   gitlab-webservice-default.gitlab.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.233.12.24

root@ansible-server:~# kubectl -n gitlab get ing
NAME                        CLASS          HOSTS                        ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE
gitlab-kas                  gitlab-nginx   kas.khaolakonline.com        10.111.0.117   80      23h
gitlab-minio                gitlab-nginx   minio.khaolakonline.com      10.111.0.117   80      23h
gitlab-registry             gitlab-nginx   registry.khaolakonline.com   10.111.0.117   80      23h
gitlab-webservice-default   gitlab-nginx   gitlab.khaolakonline.com     10.111.0.117   80      23h
root@ansible-server:~# kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- nslookup gitlab.khaolakonline.com
Server:         169.254.25.10
Address:        169.254.25.10#53

Name:   gitlab.com
Address: 10.111.0.117
```

curl

```
root@ansible-server:~# curl http://gitlab.khaolakonline.com
<html><body>You are being <a href="http://gitlab.khaolakonline.com/users/sign_in">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

Comment: Confirm that the GitLab Runner configuration (config.toml) specifies the correct URL for your GitLab instance using HTTP. Check the logs of your GitLab Runner pods and GitLab server for any error messages or issues that might provide more information about the redirection problem.